# Why realm includes .so library of all CPI architecture even if splits enabled?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, realm

My application includes libraries which doesn't support all CPU architectures, so I added

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'x86'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

to build.gradle .
However, I can still find Realm library contains every architectures, so It crashes on devices not listed above.

Any way to prevent these unnecessary .so files included?

Comment: Hmmm... maybe there is a current limitation on splits that it does not work with library modules and AARs.

Comment: No, that's not it. I just tried splits with my `cwac-anddown` library and each APK has only its own CPU architecture, so it's not a limitation of library modules or AARs. Perhaps it is something more specific to how Realm packages their app. If you can create a sample project that reproduces the problem, file an issue ("Tools Bug Report") at http://b.android.com.

Comment: @CommonsWare realm packages their libraries into a jar, I guess that's the reason. I tried https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable and it packages fine. I think it's both realm and android build tool mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Emanuele from Realm here.
The problem is that the split functionality does not work with Jar libraries, but only for the native code you include directly in your app using JNI.

I provide a solution at the end of this blog post. I hope this helps!

http://realm.io/news/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries/

> Our distribution package (available on our website under Download->Java) contains a folder called ‘eclipse’. This folder contains a split version of the Realm library. All you need to do is to copy the small jar file into the libs folder of your app and copy the four folders in the src/main/jniLibs directory.

Comment: Thank you. I think realm should provide .aar too, also I'll report this to b.android.com .